# Why matplotlib has no attribute 'pylab'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I imported `matplotlib` in the way like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
```

A error saying **'module' object has no attribute 'pylab'** was thrown out when i run the following code:

```
x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)   # import numpy as np
y = np.sin(x)
mpl.pylab.plot(x,y)
mpl.pylab.show()
```

And there was no error appears when i imported  `matplotlib` in another way:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
```

Is there anybody knows what happend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Submodules are not always imported by default.  You can import `pylab` with

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab  # Loads the pylab submodule as well
# mpl.pylab is now defined
```

This is why doing `import matplotlib.pylab as pl` solved the problem, for you.

Not importing submodules by default brings faster loading times.  It also does not pollute the main module namespace with unused submodule names.  The creator of a module can define which submodules are loaded by default (since `pylab` is quite heavy, it is not imported by default by `matplotlib`).

Answer (score 10):

To plot in non-interactive mode, you should use the module `pyplot`, not `pylab`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy

pyplot.plot(range(1,100), numpy.sin(range(1,100)))
pyplot.show()
```

The module `pylab` is not typically used as a submodule of matplotlib, but as a top-level module instead. Typically, it is used in interactive mode to bring together several parts of numpy, scipy and matplotlib into one namespace.

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> plot(range(1,100), sin(range(1,100)))
>>> show()
```

Comment: I care nothing but how to use **pylab** or **pyplot** correctly! BUT what you mentioned it's a good advice to me.

Comment: @ Chinmay: `from pyplot import *` has to be pylab, I think

Answer (score -1):

You normally get this error if the module you are trying to import does not have a `__init__.py` file.  I also get this error on my installation.  I think you just have to accept that you must import matplotlib.pylab separately from matplotlib.

Comment: Which submodules are imported by default is actually under the full control of the module creator.  In the case of `pylab`, `matplotlib/__init__.py` could in fact include a simple `import pylab` and `matplotlib.pylab` would be made available through `import matplotlib` (there is no need for it to have an `__init__.py` file).